# treeview with menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, treeview

I want to create a treeview but my problem is i dont know if is it possible to have hyperlinks in a treeview, when you click a node you see those hyperlinks that can redirect you to another form?. treeview is binded to the database

Comment: Yes it's possible you can treat treeview as menu..check out basics here...http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this `NavigateUrl` property of `TreeNode`

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="tree">
     <Nodes>
         <asp:TreeNode NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Go to default"/>
     </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set [NavigateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.navigateurl.aspx) property of TreeNode which gets or sets the URL to navigate to when the node is clicked.

You can implement NavigateUrl in following way:

```
  <asp:TreeView id="SampleTreeView" 
        runat="server">
        <Nodes>
          <asp:TreeNode Value="Home" 
            NavigateUrl="Home.aspx" 
            Text="Home"
            Target="Content" 
            Expanded="True">
            <asp:TreeNode Value="Page 1" 
              NavigateUrl="Page1.aspx" 
              Text="Page1"
              Target="Content">
              <asp:TreeNode Value="Section 1" 
                NavigateUrl="Section1.aspx" 
                Text="Section 1"
                Target="Content"/>
            </asp:TreeNode>              
            <asp:TreeNode Value="Page 2" 
              NavigateUrl="Page2.aspx"
              Text="Page 2"
              Target="Content">
            </asp:TreeNode> 
          </asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
      </asp:TreeView>
```